# Netbeans not highlighting the code that uses non existent function - php

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans7.0

I am using the following line in PHP with NetBeans 7.0 :

`$ret = $this->stupid_function();`

I certainly know that `stupid_function` doesn't exist in this class or any derivative of this.

`"Navigate to source/declaration"` takes me nowhere.

But still NetBeans doesn't seem to mark the line as error.

- I tried restarting Netbeans
- I tried re-adding the project
- I tried deleting cache

Nothing seems to work...

Although, I observed that if I removed `$this` from that statement, NetBeans knows that the function doesn't exist. It seems like NetBeans doesn't understand `$this` properly.

**How to highlight code referencing nonexistent function when using PHP in NetBeans?**

Comment: I have read the reason for no error is because functions can be created on the fly. However I still think you should be able to have a hint. It seems you still can't in Netbeans 8.2. Did you ever find a decent solution to this?

Comment: Nope! Tried the answers, none work. Also, since it did not work, I moved out of PHP :) 
6 years old question!!

Comment: Twelve years later, still an issue 

Comment: Why are you stuck with it when you can use PHPStorm? Intellij kills all these any day. @matteo

Comment: @Shrinath I've been using PHPStorm for a couple years and I'm sick of how slow and unstable it is. That's why I was trying NetBeans but indeed it's garbage. Now I'm trying VS, much better. PHPStorm is superior in how it's designed, i.e. if you consider it as a prototype of what an IDE should be, it's brilliant. But they designed it under the assumption that a 5k-line file is "huge" (their words), so, unusable in practice for any real work.

Answer (score 1):

The support for PHP highlighting is rather limited in Netbeans.

Check in <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>Hints</kbd>

Choose PHP.

You have here **the full list of supported hints** about possible errors/warnings in the code. Nothing works for me among the `Experimental` options (so *Unknow function hints* fails) in 7.0, it's slightly better in 7.1, but still doesn't work. Indeed in 7.1 they removed the *Unknow function hints* from the list.

Seems that Netbeans 7.2 has improved the highlightings quality. If you're in PHP I suggest you download the latest version of Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the magic method functionality of PHP in your class.

```
public function __call($method, $args) {
  echo "unknown method " . $method;
  return false;
}
```